# T-SQL Pivot Table By Week Missing Value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I'm a Transact SQL newbie(SQL Server 2008).

I have a pivot table that is getting these results when I search for values by date range:

```
Person     | 2/10/14 | 2/18/14 
-----------+---------+---------
Jane Doe   | NULL    | QRS 
June Jones | NULL    | XYZ 
Tom Smith  | XYZ     | HIK
```

But I need it to look like this, where June Jones has a value for 2/10/14:

```
Person     | 2/10/14 | 2/17/14 
-----------+---------+--------
Jane Doe   | NULL    | QRS 
June Jones | XYZ     | XYZ 
Tom Smith  | XYZ     | HIK
```

The problem is that June Jones has an XYZ event which has a start_dt of 2/11/14 and end_date of 2/21/14 which should be in column '2/10/14' and my query seems to be missing it. The column  of '2/17/14' is picking up the event.
My code:

```
WITH Numbers AS 
(
   SELECT '2/10/14' As n
   UNION
   SELECT '2/17/14' As n
) ,
Counted AS
(
  SELECT  s.[FirstName] + ' ' + s.[LastName] AS [Person],
  CASE WHEN s.[Event] = 'Thing1' THEN 'HIK'
       WHEN s.[Event] = 'Thing2' THEN 'QRS'
       WHEN s.[Event] = 'Thing3' THEN 'XYZ'
       ELSE NULL END AS [Info],          
      N.n AS DateWeek
  FROM  [dbo].[MyTable] s
      INNER JOIN Numbers N ON DATEADD(DD,5,N.n) BETWEEN  s.start_dt AND s.end_dt
      WHERE s.LastName in ('Doe', 'Jones', 'Smith')    
  GROUP BY s.[FirstName] + ', ' + s.[LastName], s.[Info], N.n

)
SELECT  [Person], '02/10/14', '2/17/14'
FROM  Counted
    PIVOT ( MAX(Info) FOR DateWeek IN ([2/10/14],  [2/17/14] ))
     AS PVT
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but can't see it.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the original data.

Comment: What do you need to see? This is about it. I had to strip a lot of confidential data out. I had a lot of other weeks for the pivot columns, but they all start with Monday dates if that helps. The events' start_dt all started with Monday dates too. This particular one-off which had a start_dt on 2/11/14 starts on a Tuesday. Does that help?

Comment: If you can't give us `INSERT` statements for `[MyTable]`, can you give us the output when you execute without the pivot? I.e. replace the last four lines with `SELECT * FROM Counted`

Comment: Person, Event, DateWeek<br>
Jane Doe, NULL, 2/10/2014<br>
Jane Doe,  WF,  02/18/2014<br>
Jane Doe,  WF,  02/24/2014<br>
June Jones,  BOH, 02/18/2014<br>
June Jones,  CNC, 02/24/2014<br>
Tom Smith,  BOH,  02/10/2014<br>
Tom Smith,  EWB,  02/18/2014<br>
Tom Smith.  BOH,  02/24/2014<br>
Tom Smith,  IMB, 03/3/2014 <br>

Comment: I see that 2/10 isn't showing up for June Jones at all when I do select * from counted. Is this better?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For 10th obiously it show null because your event start on 11th.

Comment: Sorry it's been a few days. Got the answer on my own. Thanks.